# discord.py: How to change server icon

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want to change server icon.
Trying this:

```
await bot.edit_server(ctx.message.server, icon_url="http://some.thing/image.png)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `icon` instead, a `bytes`-like object. So if you have a file `image.jpg` you could do

```
with open('image.jpg', 'rb') as f:
    icon = f.read()
await bot.edit_server(ctx.message.server, icon=icon)
```

In your example, you'll need to download that image into a `bytes`, and then use that to `edit_server`

Comment: If you do `await bot.edit_server(ctx.message.server, icon=None)` instead, does that remove the avatar?  What file type are you trying to use? Do you have the proper permissions to edit the server? Are you doing any exception handling (try/except, etc.) that could be suppressing error messages from this coroutine?

Comment: I would rather prefer doing: `ctx.message.server.edit(icon-icon)`